# Cloudmin OpenVZ disk inodes issues

Tags: server, virtualization, inode, webmin, openvz

I have been beating my head on these for days now, when i create VM (OpenVZ based) using Cloudmin CP or API, i dont know why the inode is always small and i have to edit inode from host machine to make it work

For example i created a vm with 100GB disk space and the inode is as small so the server runs out of space easily

See below when i run df -h and df -i

```
root@mongodb1:/# df -i                                                          
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on                           
/dev/simfs      131072 27153  103919   21% /                                    
tmpfs          1088000    39 1087961    1% /run                                 
tmpfs          1088000     1 1087999    1% /run/lock                            
tmpfs          1088000     2 1087998    1% /run/shm                             

root@mongodb1:/# df -h                                                          
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on                                
/dev/simfs       98G  785M   97G   1% /                                         
tmpfs           850M  980K  850M   1% /run                                      
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock                                 
tmpfs           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /run/shm
```

Has any experienced this ans what did you do

Answer (score 1):

I cannot post comments yet, but I would have asked what kernel version you are running (uname -r) and how you create your guests.  So I will try to answer as best I can using the output you provided.

It looks like you are using simfs for your filesystem, so I am guessing this is an OpenVZ legacy version (2.6.x kernel).

I do not know how you are creating your virtual private server, but if you do not pass the --config option to vzctl then you get the defaults.  I believe the defaults come from the file specified in the /etc/vz/vz.conf CONFIGFILE variable (run these commands in the shell on your host to find out what it is):

```
declare $(grep CONFIGFILE /etc/vz/vz.conf)
ls /etc/vz/conf/ve-$(sed -e "s/\"\|\'//g" <<<"$CONFIGFILE").conf-sample
```

edit that resulting file and alter the DISKINODES option to change the default.

You could also create your own configuration file by making a new file /etc/vz/conf/ve-SOME_NAME.conf-sample and put all the parameters you want for a new server then creating your guest with:

```
vzctl create VEID --config SOME_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks alot, testing this, I will soon update you back

Comment: Worked i was mixing the method before